# Error message while adding AWS SSO SAML app in gsuite "Can't add AWS SSO. Please try again"

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, google-workspace

I am facing an issue when adding a SAML APP within gsuite for AWS SSO. We are using google as an external identity provider for AWS SSO. I get the following error message "Can't add AWS SSO. Please try again" when adding the app AWS SSO in Gsuite. Did any one here encountered this issue before ?

PS: I have the super admin rights in gsuite and i m following the official AWS documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you recently created the Google Workspace account or has your account been granted with Super Admin permissions in the last 24-48 hours? If so, the problem is related to propagation and you would just need to wait from 24 to 48 hours and try again.

In case you need this ASAP and the account has an older super admin, then you could ask the older super admin to do it for you.

You can confirm the propagation issue in the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176).

> "The user typically becomes an admin within a few minutes. However, it can take up to 24 hours".

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved after i contacted google support team. In fact, it has nothing to do with my Saml app set up or super admin rights. According to them, it was an internal problem they had. I asked for more details but i didnt get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting all kinds of strange errors.  I can confirm if you just opened a workspace account and setup SSO in AWS it took 2 days to propagate and is now working great.  Hopefully this helps someone else from chasing their tail.